# Downsizing Elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I tried to downsize the node type of my Elasticache from **cache.r4.large** to **cache.t2.medium** but it does not proceed.

what happened is after I modify.. The **Status** of my Cluster will become **Modifying** but after a few minutes, the status will become **Available** but the node type did not change at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes aren't applied till the next maintenance window. Select the apply immediately option to scale down immediately.